# How to detect GraphQL endpoint using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql, endpoint, graphql-python

I am trying to detect a graphql endpoint using Python language. I am an absolute beginner , but i have tried to make a code. 
Can you please suggest changes and better ways to do it?
CODE:

```
import requests,urllib,urllib.request
import string
consoleDict = [
    "",
    "/graphql",
    "/graphql/console",
    "graphql.php",
    "graphiql",
    "explorer",
    "altair",
    "/playground"
          ]
for endpoint in consoleDict:
    ep = ' http://159.100.248.211 '
    response = requests.get(ep)
    if response.status_code in [200,403]:
        print("It is a GraphQL endpoint",endpoint)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You'll probably want to use a graphql client library, such as [gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql)

Comment: hey , can you tell me how , maybe help me with the code. I am absolute beginner at it so :3

Comment: You're not using the `endpoint` variable at all. Then you're always making requests to the same host http:159.100.248.211.

Answer (score 0):

Even with `gql`, you need the schema to ask for anything. If you don't know it, you could use introspection query:

```
{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Some endpoints might have this disabled, but if you don't know the schema it is a good starting point.
Try with something like this:

```py
import json
import requests
from urllib import parse

paths = [
    "",
    "/graphql",
    "/graphql/console",
    "graphql.php",
    "graphiql",
    "explorer",
    "altair",
    "/playground"
]

query = """{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
    }
  }
}
"""

for path in paths:
    hostname = 'http://159.100.248.211'
    endpoint = parse.urljoin(hostname, path)
    try:
        print(f"Attempt: {endpoint}")
        response = requests.post(endpoint, json={'query': query}, timeout=0.1)
    except Exception:
        print("No GraphQL endpoint found")
    else:
        if response.status_code == 200:
            json_data = json.loads(response.text)
            if json_data.get('data'):
                print("It is a GraphQL endpoint",endpoint)
```

Let mw know if this works